# connection to database throwing up an error - Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ',' in C:\xampp\htdocs\newlogin\forgotpass.php on line 19

Tags: php, mysql

when attempting to connect to the database - connect, the following error is provided:Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ',' in C:\xampp\htdocs\newlogin\forgotpass.php on line 19

```
<form action="" method="POST">
your email: <br /><input ="text" name="email" size"30"/><br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

<?php
$email= $POST['email'];
$submit =$POST['submit'];
//
-->$connect= ("localhost","root","black$23");
mysql_select_db ("login_site",$connect);
if ($submit) {

    $email_check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='".$email."'");
    $count=mysql_num_rows($email_check);

    if ($count !=0){
    $random=rand(72891, 92729);
    $new_password=$random;
    $email_password=$new_password;

    require('blowfish.php');
    require('bcrypt.class.php');

    $bcrypt= new Bcrypt(4);
$new_password= $bcrypt->hash($new_password);
echo $new_password;

mysql_query("update users set password='".$new_password."'where email='".$email."'");



    }
    else{
        echo "This email does not exist.";
    }

}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: mysql_* is deprecated. please do not use it any more.

Comment: Maybe the `-->` on line 10? The indentation of your `if ($count !=0)` statement could do with tidying too, for our benefit as well as yours.

Comment: Which line is line 19?

Comment: Erk! `$connect=("localhost","root","black$23");` is missing a function name. I would advise you to install an IDE - it will do automatic syntax checking that will help you resolve these sorts of errors quickly.

Comment: You have SQL injection vulnerabilities in this code too.

Comment: What @Jens is saying is that you should look into mysqli_ functions or PDO as mysql_ functions have been depreciated for some time now due to performance. Reagrding SQL injection that Halfer mentioned, you need to escape user inputed values (_POST,_GET) by parsing them through mysqli_real_escape_string() or similar.

Comment: Am testing the code, sorry if it is a bit sloppy

Answer (score 1):

Line 10 (`-->$connect= ("localhost","root","black$23");`) should be:

```
$connect = mysql_connect("localhost","root","black$23");
```

Note, `mysql_*` functions are deprecated, use `mysqli_*` or PDOs instead.